# How to hide the summarized details in RadGrid Footer

Tags: radgrid

GroupingSettings ShowUnGroupButton="true" RetainGroupFootersVisibility="true"

In RadGrid Group Footer by setting above property it is showing summarize of data with details. but in situation I want to hide this details and want to show only summarize total details not data.

any helps are appreciate.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: give the code as code format don't give as the plain text

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/groupby/groupfooter/defaultcs.aspx. you get full code from this link...

Comment: If you hide header of group then, how can you expand/collapse the group header?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GridCalculatedColumn feature to do this.

See the working [DEMO over here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/calculatedcolumns/defaultcs.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it will display summarized data with details.. but i want only 'total summarized' details